# C# asp.net parameters cast to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

if you please help me out i am trying to pass 3 different parameters in a page but i am new in asp.net C#  and i don't know the correct syntax  if you please help me out

;

For one parameter like this it works:

```
 Response.Redirect("~/WebPage2.aspx?q=" + ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

how can i write it for 3 parameters like this don't seem  to work?

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebPage2.aspx?q=" + ListBox1.SelectedValue+"&cr="+ListBox3.SelectedValue+"&p="+ListBox1.SelectedValue)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `+` in your string concatenations after the `cr` parameter. This being said a far safer and better approach which ensures that your parameters are properly encoded is the following:

```
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
parameters["q"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
parameters["cr"] = ListBox3.SelectedValue;
parameters["p"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
var url = string.Format("~/WebPage2.aspx?{0}", parameters.ToString());
Response.Redirect(url);
```

And of course if you are using ASP.NET MVC (as you've tagged your question with it) you would use:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { 
    q = ListBox1.SelectedValue,
    cr = ListBox3.SelectedValue,
    p = ListBox1.SelectedValue
});
```

I very sincerely hope that if you are using ASP.NET MVC then `ListBox1` and `ListBox2` is not what I think it is.

Comment: Let's hope Response.Redirect() is too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I typically do (assuming a constant number of parameters for each URL):

```
string url = "~/WebPage2.aspx?q={q}&cr={cr}&p={p}";

url = url.Replace("{q}", ListBox1.SelectedValue)
         .Replace("{cr}", ListBox2.SelectedValue)
         .Replace("{q}", ListBox3.SelectedValue);

Response.Redirect(url);
```

I have not tested it, but this may be relatively inefficient. The reason I do it this way is so I know exactly what the URL pattern looks like and which parameters are used.

It's a trade-off to be sure, and am curious to see other peoples' feedback.